# Read a properties file from a given folder in Java EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm defining a **Java EE project** as follows:

```
MyProjectRoot
+- src/main/java
    +- my.package.MyClass.java
+- src/test/java
    +- my.package.MyClassTest.java
+- src/main/recources/
    +- application.properties
```

Supposing that I'd like to use code as follows in order to read data from the application.properties file:

```
InputStream inputStream  = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PATH);
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(inputStream);
```

Which is the right **PATH** definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
InputStream inputStream  = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/application.properties");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(inputStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give only the file name which is under the resources folder. For example "application.properties" is enough for PATH definition